# jQuery fadeToggle cache / localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, local-storage, toggle

lets say i have a cube and i wanna to hide/show him with 1 button.
How can I cache the toggle state so when I hide the Cube via the button and refresh the page the cube is still hidden? A toggleClass resolution would be usefull also.

```
<div id="cube" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;"></div>

<button id="trigger">trigger</button>
```

My jQuery test:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){
  $('#cube').fadeToggle('fast');});
```

Comment: use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply set a global atribute on [window](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) object,

```
window[attrName] = value;
```

see follow:

```js
$('#trigger').click(function(){
  fadeToogle();
});

function fadeToogle(){
  if(window["myState"] && window["myState"]=="on"){
      $('#cube').fadeIn('fast');
      window["myState"] = "off";
  } else {
    $('#cube').fadeOut('fast');
    window["myState"] = "on";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cube" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;"></div>

<button id="trigger">trigger</button>
```

You could also use `localStorage` but you can get errors about CROSS origin or browser compatibility.

Comment: I think localStorage would be better. Any ideas how to do something like that? I did a few tests but they didnt work.

Comment: To write it `localStorage.setItem("myState", "off");` and to read `localStorage.myState`

Comment: Thank you very much guys

Comment: I'm glad, please don't forget to accept/upvote answer when is useful. Thanks.